# How to move from Queue class to Stack class and then a calculate function?

Tags: python, stack, queue

I am trying to make a program that allows the user to make a logic gate circuit by typing in either a logic gate, an input and an output. The program currently adds the inputs to a queue and when output is written, the inputs should be removed from the queue and added to the stack for calculation. When the stack is full with 3 items it will calculate the 3 items and return the answer to the stack. When I run my code it keeps on saying that I'm popping from an empty stack and I don't know how to fix it. The user has to type in the inputs first then the gate and last write output. Example: 1 AND 0 NOT OUTPUT would be typed in like 1 O AND NOT OUTPUT to the program. I really need help as I have been trying to do this for weeks please.

```
class Queue():
   def __init__(self):
      self.queue = []
      self.__frontPtr = 0
      self.__rearPtr = 0
      self.__maxLength = 10
      self.__length =0

   def addToQ(self,newGate):
      self.queue.insert(0,newGate)
      self.__rearPtr+=1

   def empty(self):
      self.queue = []
      self.__frontPtr = 0
      self.__rearPtr = 0
      return(self.queue,self.__frontPtr,self.__rearPtr)

   def isEmpty(self):
      return self.queue==[]

   def removeFromQ(self):
      return self.queue.pop()

   def displayQ(self):
      print(self.queue)
      print("\n")

   def size(self):
      return (len(self.queue))


class Stack():
   def __init__(self):
      self.stack=[]

   def isEmpty(self):
      return self.stack==[]

   def push(self,newItem):
      self.stack.append(newItem)

   def pop(self):
      return self.stack.pop()

   def empty(self):
      self.stack=[]

   def size(self):
      return len(self.stack)

   def display(self):
      print(self.stack)
      print("\n")


class Calculation(Stack,Queue):
   def __init__(self):
      self.answer=0
      self.myStack=Stack()
      self.myQueue=Queue()


   def isFull(self):
      if self.myStack.size()!=3:
         self.moveToStack()
      else:
         self.calculate()

   def moveToStack(self):
      newItem=self.myQueue.removeFromQ()
      self.myStack.push(newItem)
      self.isFull()


   def calculate():
      item1=self.myStack.pop()
      print(item1)
      item2=self.myStack.pop()
      if item2=="notgate":
         if item3=="one":
            answer=0
            self.myStack.push(0)
         else:
            answer=1
            self.myStack.push(0)
      else:
         item3=self.myStack.pop()


      if item1=="andgate":
         if item2=="one" and item3=="one":
            answer=1
            self.myStack.push(1)
         else:
            answer=0
            self.myStack.push(0)


      elif item1=="nandgate":
         if item2=="one" and item3=="one":
            answer=0
            self.myStack.push(0)
         elif item2=="one" and item3=="zero":
            answer=1
            self.myStack.push(1)
         elif item2=="zero" and item3=="one":
            answer=1
            self.myStack.push(1)
         else:
            answer=1
            self.myStack.push(1)

      elif item1=="norgate":
         if item2=="zero" and item3=="zero":
            answer=1
            self.myStack.push(1)
         elif item2=="one" and item3=="zero":
            answer=0
            self.myStack.push(0)
         elif item2=="zero" and item3=="one":
            answer=0
            self.myStack.push(0)
         else:
            answer=0
            self.myStack.push(0)

      elif item1=="xorgate":
         if item2=="one" and item3=="zero":
            answer=0
            self.myStack.push(0)
         elif item2=="zero" and item3=="one":
            answer=0
            self.myStack.push(0)
         elif item2=="zero" and item3=="zero":
            answer=1
            self.myStack.push(1)
         else:
            answer=1
            self.myStack.push(1)

      elif item1=="orgate":
         if item2=="one":
            answer=1
            self.myStack.push(1)
         elif item3=="one":
            answer=1
            self.myStack.push(1)
         else:
            answer=0
            self.myStack.push(0)

    #  if self.myStack.size()<3:
     #    self.moveToStack()

      if self.myQueue.size()==0:
         print("output is", self.myStack.pop())

circuitInput=str(input("Enter circuit item: "))
gateQueue=Queue()
gateStack=Stack()
gateCal=Calculation()
while circuitInput!="output":
   circuitInput=str(input("Enter circuit item: "))
   gateQueue.addToQ(circuitInput)
gateQueue.addToQ("output")
gateCal.isFull()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not the minimal code necessary to explain the problem. Please include a [MCVE].

Comment: Ok, I have minimised my code. I have tried adding a recursive function that calls itself it the stack is not full but it still doesn't work so I removed it.